# Using StageWebView to open web sites that contains flash contents without the need to the flash player on IOS?

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, stagewebview

I have a native flash application which works like a web browser using the StageWebView,
I need a way to open the websites that contains flash contents without the need to the flash player to be installed (i.e. i want the adobe air framework to act as the flash player without the need to for it to be installed).

I need this application to be able to run flash files located in any web page using its framework which is built in my web browser files.

If this works it will solve the problem for iPad/iPhone since there is no flash player for them.

I have removed the flash plugins and any flash application from an android device, and tried to run several web controls but none of them were able to run the flash elements.

If there is any library or control, freeware or can be tested it will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for isn't possible.

The `StageWebView` uses the available native browser components on iOS and Android, rather than its own engine.  Since the iOS browser does not have a Flash plugin, neither will your embedded browser.  (It uses its own engine on the Desktop; I'm not sure about plugin support.)

On Android, you can enable Flash Player, if available, but you need to [request hardware acceration](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html#WS365a66ad37c9f5102ec8a8ba12f2d91095a-8000).

Comment: Air contained Flash plugin until version 27 If I remember well